# Store next record from the list to the global variable using Groovy

Tags: loops, groovy, soapui

I am trying to check availability of room and if availability fails then select next room from the list until room is available for booking.
e.g : Records contains RoomID and Timezone.
[image]

Groovy Code :

```
def isAvailable = false
def SDT = context.expand('${#Project#StartDateTime}') 
def EDT = context.expand('${#Project#EndDateTime}') 

while( isAvailable==false ) 
{
//Running while loop and checking slot availability.
def res = con.eachRow("select * from tblbookingitem where active=1 and fkItemID=$roomID and DateTimeFrom='$SDT' and DateTimeTo='$EDT'" )
if(res== null) // if null that means slot is available
    {
        log.info "Step 2 : Time slot is available."
        isAvailable=true;       
        context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('RoomID', roomID)
        log.info roomID
        break;       
    }
else
    {
        //Store next room in roomID
//Store RoomID to variable
def res2 = con.eachRow("select pkResourceItemsID,locationTimeZone,* from tblResourceItems ri inner join Enterprise.tblRooms r on ri.pkResourceItemsID=r.roomID where ri.active=1 and ri.fkResourceID=1 and r.fkresourceId=1 and r.deliveryPoint=0 order by ri.pkResourceItemsID asc" )

log.info res2.pkResourceItemsID.toString()

context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("RoomID", res2.pkResourceItemsID.toString())

//Store Timezone to variable
log.info res2.locationTimeZone.toString()
context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("Timezone", res2.locationTimeZone.toString())
}
}
```

In else part i need the second record to store in RoomID and Timezone.
When next time availability fails again then it should pick third record and so on...

Comment: What if even next record /room is not available?

Comment: Then it should pick third record and so on....until availability true.

Comment: Don't query returns the free room directly? Will you be able to apply the filter in the query?

Comment: Yes, Actually i am thinking of applying FOR loop directly rather than using WHILE loop. e.g :
def res2 = con.rows("select pkResourceItemsID,locationTimeZone from tblResourceItems ri inner join Enterprise.tblRooms r on ri.pkResourceItemsID=r.roomID where ri.active=1 and ri.fkResourceID=1 and r.fkresourceId=1 and r.deliveryPoint=0 order by ri.pkResourceItemsID asc" )

int LIST = res2.size() //2473 rows
log.info LIST
//def i
for(int i = 0; i < LIST; i++)
{  
 log.info res2[1].pkResourceItemsID
 log.info res2[1].locationTimeZone 
}

Comment: Can you update the question please instead of comment as it is not readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def res2 = con.rows("select pkResourceItemsID,locationTimeZone from tblResourceItems ri inner join Enterprise.tblRooms r on ri.pkResourceItemsID=r.roomID where ri.active=1 and ri.fkResourceID=1 and r.fkresourceId=1 and r.deliveryPoint=0 order by ri.pkResourceItemsID asc" )

int LIST = res2.size() 
log.info "Total Rooms : " + LIST

for(int i = 0; i < LIST; i++)
{       
    log.info "Step 1 : Run for loop for each Room in Record Set."

    //1.Set New RoomID and TimeZone to Global variable
    roomID = res2[i].pkResourceItemsID
    TZ = res2[i].locationTimeZone

    def res = con.firstRow("select * from tblbookingitem where fkItemID=$roomID and DateTimeFrom='$nSDT' and DateTimeTo='$nEDT'" )
    if(res== null) // if null that means slot is available
    {
        log.info "Step 2 : Time slot is available."     
        break;       
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the above one a solution? or an edit to the question?

Comment: @Rao That's the solution.